# Relationship between ELF files and Process Control Blocks

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, elf

Could someone explain the relationship between ELF files which from my understanding are the final executable file which is used by Unix-based OS' to start any application and the PCB (Process Control Blocks) is the program context which stores information about the running process. Obviously, these are two very different things I just want to know how they relate to each other, does the ELF file specify what is stored in a PCB or does the OS have a consistent PCB structure for every application?

Comment: Are you asking about Linux specifically? For what architecture? What kernel version? Read [a good operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: "does the ELF file specify what is stored in a PCB" -- given that Linux can run both `ELF` and `a.out` format executables (among others), the answer is clearly "no".

Answer (score 0):

The OS has a consistent struct for every application running. On Linux, it is the task_struct:

```
struct task_struct {
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /*
     * For reasons of header soup (see current_thread_info()), this
     * must be the first element of task_struct.
     */
    struct thread_info      thread_info;
#endif
    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped: */
    volatile long           state;

    /*
     * This begins the randomizable portion of task_struct. Only
     * scheduling-critical items should be added above here.
     */
    randomized_struct_fields_start

    void                *stack;
    refcount_t          usage;
    /* Per task flags (PF_*), defined further below: */
    unsigned int            flags;
    unsigned int            ptrace;

#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    int             on_cpu;
    struct __call_single_node   wake_entry;
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /* Current CPU: */
    unsigned int            cpu;
#endif
    unsigned int            wakee_flips;
    unsigned long           wakee_flip_decay_ts;
    struct task_struct      *last_wakee;

    /*
     * recent_used_cpu is initially set as the last CPU used by a task
     * that wakes affine another task. Waker/wakee relationships can
     * push tasks around a CPU where each wakeup moves to the next one.
     * Tracking a recently used CPU allows a quick search for a recently
     * used CPU that may be idle.
     */
    int             recent_used_cpu;
    int             wake_cpu;
#endif
    int             on_rq;

    int             prio;
    int             static_prio;
    int             normal_prio;
    unsigned int            rt_priority;

    const struct sched_class    *sched_class;
    struct sched_entity     se;
    struct sched_rt_entity      rt;
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED
    struct task_group       *sched_task_group;
#endif
    struct sched_dl_entity      dl;

#ifdef CONFIG_UCLAMP_TASK
    /*
     * Clamp values requested for a scheduling entity.
     * Must be updated with task_rq_lock() held.
     */
    struct uclamp_se        uclamp_req[UCLAMP_CNT];
    /*
     * Effective clamp values used for a scheduling entity.
     * Must be updated with task_rq_lock() held.
     */
    struct uclamp_se        uclamp[UCLAMP_CNT];
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS
    /* List of struct preempt_notifier: */
    struct hlist_head       preempt_notifiers;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE
    unsigned int            btrace_seq;
#endif

    unsigned int            policy;
    int             nr_cpus_allowed;
    const cpumask_t         *cpus_ptr;
    cpumask_t           cpus_mask;
    void                *migration_pending;
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    unsigned short          migration_disabled;
#endif
    unsigned short          migration_flags;

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU
    int             rcu_read_lock_nesting;
    union rcu_special       rcu_read_unlock_special;
    struct list_head        rcu_node_entry;
    struct rcu_node         *rcu_blocked_node;
#endif /* #ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU */

#ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_RCU
    unsigned long           rcu_tasks_nvcsw;
    u8              rcu_tasks_holdout;
    u8              rcu_tasks_idx;
    int             rcu_tasks_idle_cpu;
    struct list_head        rcu_tasks_holdout_list;
#endif /* #ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_RCU */

#ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_TRACE_RCU
    int             trc_reader_nesting;
    int             trc_ipi_to_cpu;
    union rcu_special       trc_reader_special;
    bool                trc_reader_checked;
    struct list_head        trc_holdout_list;
#endif /* #ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_TRACE_RCU */

    struct sched_info       sched_info;

    struct list_head        tasks;
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    struct plist_node       pushable_tasks;
    struct rb_node          pushable_dl_tasks;
#endif

    struct mm_struct        *mm;
    struct mm_struct        *active_mm;

    /* Per-thread vma caching: */
    struct vmacache         vmacache;

#ifdef SPLIT_RSS_COUNTING
    struct task_rss_stat        rss_stat;
#endif
    int             exit_state;
    int             exit_code;
    int             exit_signal;
    /* The signal sent when the parent dies: */
    int             pdeath_signal;
    /* JOBCTL_*, siglock protected: */
    unsigned long           jobctl;

    /* Used for emulating ABI behavior of previous Linux versions: */
    unsigned int            personality;

    /* Scheduler bits, serialized by scheduler locks: */
    unsigned            sched_reset_on_fork:1;
    unsigned            sched_contributes_to_load:1;
    unsigned            sched_migrated:1;
#ifdef CONFIG_PSI
    unsigned            sched_psi_wake_requeue:1;
#endif

    /* Force alignment to the next boundary: */
    unsigned            :0;

    /* Unserialized, strictly 'current' */

    /*
     * This field must not be in the scheduler word above due to wakelist
     * queueing no longer being serialized by p->on_cpu. However:
     *
     * p->XXX = X;          ttwu()
     * schedule()             if (p->on_rq && ..) // false
     *   smp_mb__after_spinlock();    if (smp_load_acquire(&p->on_cpu) && //true
     *   deactivate_task()            ttwu_queue_wakelist())
     *     p->on_rq = 0;            p->sched_remote_wakeup = Y;
     *
     * guarantees all stores of 'current' are visible before
     * ->sched_remote_wakeup gets used, so it can be in this word.
     */
    unsigned            sched_remote_wakeup:1;

    /* Bit to tell LSMs we're in execve(): */
    unsigned            in_execve:1;
    unsigned            in_iowait:1;
#ifndef TIF_RESTORE_SIGMASK
    unsigned            restore_sigmask:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MEMCG
    unsigned            in_user_fault:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT_BRK
    unsigned            brk_randomized:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUPS
    /* disallow userland-initiated cgroup migration */
    unsigned            no_cgroup_migration:1;
    /* task is frozen/stopped (used by the cgroup freezer) */
    unsigned            frozen:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP
    unsigned            use_memdelay:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_PSI
    /* Stalled due to lack of memory */
    unsigned            in_memstall:1;
#endif

    unsigned long           atomic_flags; /* Flags requiring atomic access. */

    struct restart_block        restart_block;

    pid_t               pid;
    pid_t               tgid;

#ifdef CONFIG_STACKPROTECTOR
    /* Canary value for the -fstack-protector GCC feature: */
    unsigned long           stack_canary;
#endif
    /*
     * Pointers to the (original) parent process, youngest child, younger sibling,
     * older sibling, respectively.  (p->father can be replaced with
     * p->real_parent->pid)
     */

    /* Real parent process: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *real_parent;

    /* Recipient of SIGCHLD, wait4() reports: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *parent;

    /*
     * Children/sibling form the list of natural children:
     */
    struct list_head        children;
    struct list_head        sibling;
    struct task_struct      *group_leader;

    /*
     * 'ptraced' is the list of tasks this task is using ptrace() on.
     *
     * This includes both natural children and PTRACE_ATTACH targets.
     * 'ptrace_entry' is this task's link on the p->parent->ptraced list.
     */
    struct list_head        ptraced;
    struct list_head        ptrace_entry;

    /* PID/PID hash table linkage. */
    struct pid          *thread_pid;
    struct hlist_node       pid_links[PIDTYPE_MAX];
    struct list_head        thread_group;
    struct list_head        thread_node;

    struct completion       *vfork_done;

    /* CLONE_CHILD_SETTID: */
    int __user          *set_child_tid;

    /* CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID: */
    int __user          *clear_child_tid;

    u64             utime;
    u64             stime;
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SCALED_CPUTIME
    u64             utimescaled;
    u64             stimescaled;
#endif
    u64             gtime;
    struct prev_cputime     prev_cputime;
#ifdef CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN
    struct vtime            vtime;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL
    atomic_t            tick_dep_mask;
#endif
    /* Context switch counts: */
    unsigned long           nvcsw;
    unsigned long           nivcsw;

    /* Monotonic time in nsecs: */
    u64             start_time;

    /* Boot based time in nsecs: */
    u64             start_boottime;

    /* MM fault and swap info: this can arguably be seen as either mm-specific or thread-specific: */
    unsigned long           min_flt;
    unsigned long           maj_flt;

    /* Empty if CONFIG_POSIX_CPUTIMERS=n */
    struct posix_cputimers      posix_cputimers;

#ifdef CONFIG_POSIX_CPU_TIMERS_TASK_WORK
    struct posix_cputimers_work posix_cputimers_work;
#endif

    /* Process credentials: */

    /* Tracer's credentials at attach: */
    const struct cred __rcu     *ptracer_cred;

    /* Objective and real subjective task credentials (COW): */
    const struct cred __rcu     *real_cred;

    /* Effective (overridable) subjective task credentials (COW): */
    const struct cred __rcu     *cred;

#ifdef CONFIG_KEYS
    /* Cached requested key. */
    struct key          *cached_requested_key;
#endif

    /*
     * executable name, excluding path.
     *
     * - normally initialized setup_new_exec()
     * - access it with [gs]et_task_comm()
     * - lock it with task_lock()
     */
    char                comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];

    struct nameidata        *nameidata;

#ifdef CONFIG_SYSVIPC
    struct sysv_sem         sysvsem;
    struct sysv_shm         sysvshm;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK
    unsigned long           last_switch_count;
    unsigned long           last_switch_time;
#endif
    /* Filesystem information: */
    struct fs_struct        *fs;

    /* Open file information: */
    struct files_struct     *files;

#ifdef CONFIG_IO_URING
    struct io_uring_task        *io_uring;
#endif

    /* Namespaces: */
    struct nsproxy          *nsproxy;

    /* Signal handlers: */
    struct signal_struct        *signal;
    struct sighand_struct __rcu     *sighand;
    sigset_t            blocked;
    sigset_t            real_blocked;
    /* Restored if set_restore_sigmask() was used: */
    sigset_t            saved_sigmask;
    struct sigpending       pending;
    unsigned long           sas_ss_sp;
    size_t              sas_ss_size;
    unsigned int            sas_ss_flags;

    struct callback_head        *task_works;

#ifdef CONFIG_AUDIT
#ifdef CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL
    struct audit_context        *audit_context;
#endif
    kuid_t              loginuid;
    unsigned int            sessionid;
#endif
    struct seccomp          seccomp;
    struct syscall_user_dispatch    syscall_dispatch;

    /* Thread group tracking: */
    u64             parent_exec_id;
    u64             self_exec_id;

    /* Protection against (de-)allocation: mm, files, fs, tty, keyrings, mems_allowed, mempolicy: */
    spinlock_t          alloc_lock;

    /* Protection of the PI data structures: */
    raw_spinlock_t          pi_lock;

    struct wake_q_node      wake_q;

#ifdef CONFIG_RT_MUTEXES
    /* PI waiters blocked on a rt_mutex held by this task: */
    struct rb_root_cached       pi_waiters;
    /* Updated under owner's pi_lock and rq lock */
    struct task_struct      *pi_top_task;
    /* Deadlock detection and priority inheritance handling: */
    struct rt_mutex_waiter      *pi_blocked_on;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES
    /* Mutex deadlock detection: */
    struct mutex_waiter     *blocked_on;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP
    int             non_block_count;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS
    struct irqtrace_events      irqtrace;
    unsigned int            hardirq_threaded;
    u64             hardirq_chain_key;
    int             softirqs_enabled;
    int             softirq_context;
    int             irq_config;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
# define MAX_LOCK_DEPTH         48UL
    u64             curr_chain_key;
    int             lockdep_depth;
    unsigned int            lockdep_recursion;
    struct held_lock        held_locks[MAX_LOCK_DEPTH];
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_UBSAN) && !defined(CONFIG_UBSAN_TRAP)
    unsigned int            in_ubsan;
#endif

    /* Journalling filesystem info: */
    void                *journal_info;

    /* Stacked block device info: */
    struct bio_list         *bio_list;

#ifdef CONFIG_BLOCK
    /* Stack plugging: */
    struct blk_plug         *plug;
#endif

    /* VM state: */
    struct reclaim_state        *reclaim_state;

    struct backing_dev_info     *backing_dev_info;

    struct io_context       *io_context;

#ifdef CONFIG_COMPACTION
    struct capture_control      *capture_control;
#endif
    /* Ptrace state: */
    unsigned long           ptrace_message;
    kernel_siginfo_t        *last_siginfo;

    struct task_io_accounting   ioac;
#ifdef CONFIG_PSI
    /* Pressure stall state */
    unsigned int            psi_flags;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_XACCT
    /* Accumulated RSS usage: */
    u64             acct_rss_mem1;
    /* Accumulated virtual memory usage: */
    u64             acct_vm_mem1;
    /* stime + utime since last update: */
    u64             acct_timexpd;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CPUSETS
    /* Protected by ->alloc_lock: */
    nodemask_t          mems_allowed;
    /* Seqence number to catch updates: */
    seqcount_spinlock_t     mems_allowed_seq;
    int             cpuset_mem_spread_rotor;
    int             cpuset_slab_spread_rotor;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUPS
    /* Control Group info protected by css_set_lock: */
    struct css_set __rcu        *cgroups;
    /* cg_list protected by css_set_lock and tsk->alloc_lock: */
    struct list_head        cg_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_CPU_RESCTRL
    u32             closid;
    u32             rmid;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_FUTEX
    struct robust_list_head __user  *robust_list;
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
    struct compat_robust_list_head __user *compat_robust_list;
#endif
    struct list_head        pi_state_list;
    struct futex_pi_state       *pi_state_cache;
    struct mutex            futex_exit_mutex;
    unsigned int            futex_state;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS
    struct perf_event_context   *perf_event_ctxp[perf_nr_task_contexts];
    struct mutex            perf_event_mutex;
    struct list_head        perf_event_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT
    unsigned long           preempt_disable_ip;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA
    /* Protected by alloc_lock: */
    struct mempolicy        *mempolicy;
    short               il_prev;
    short               pref_node_fork;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA_BALANCING
    int             numa_scan_seq;
    unsigned int            numa_scan_period;
    unsigned int            numa_scan_period_max;
    int             numa_preferred_nid;
    unsigned long           numa_migrate_retry;
    /* Migration stamp: */
    u64             node_stamp;
    u64             last_task_numa_placement;
    u64             last_sum_exec_runtime;
    struct callback_head        numa_work;

    /*
     * This pointer is only modified for current in syscall and
     * pagefault context (and for tasks being destroyed), so it can be read
     * from any of the following contexts:
     *  - RCU read-side critical section
     *  - current->numa_group from everywhere
     *  - task's runqueue locked, task not running
     */
    struct numa_group __rcu     *numa_group;

    /*
     * numa_faults is an array split into four regions:
     * faults_memory, faults_cpu, faults_memory_buffer, faults_cpu_buffer
     * in this precise order.
     *
     * faults_memory: Exponential decaying average of faults on a per-node
     * basis. Scheduling placement decisions are made based on these
     * counts. The values remain static for the duration of a PTE scan.
     * faults_cpu: Track the nodes the process was running on when a NUMA
     * hinting fault was incurred.
     * faults_memory_buffer and faults_cpu_buffer: Record faults per node
     * during the current scan window. When the scan completes, the counts
     * in faults_memory and faults_cpu decay and these values are copied.
     */
    unsigned long           *numa_faults;
    unsigned long           total_numa_faults;

    /*
     * numa_faults_locality tracks if faults recorded during the last
     * scan window were remote/local or failed to migrate. The task scan
     * period is adapted based on the locality of the faults with different
     * weights depending on whether they were shared or private faults
     */
    unsigned long           numa_faults_locality[3];

    unsigned long           numa_pages_migrated;
#endif /* CONFIG_NUMA_BALANCING */

#ifdef CONFIG_RSEQ
    struct rseq __user *rseq;
    u32 rseq_sig;
    /*
     * RmW on rseq_event_mask must be performed atomically
     * with respect to preemption.
     */
    unsigned long rseq_event_mask;
#endif

    struct tlbflush_unmap_batch tlb_ubc;

    union {
        refcount_t      rcu_users;
        struct rcu_head     rcu;
    };

    /* Cache last used pipe for splice(): */
    struct pipe_inode_info      *splice_pipe;

    struct page_frag        task_frag;

#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT
    struct task_delay_info      *delays;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_FAULT_INJECTION
    int             make_it_fail;
    unsigned int            fail_nth;
#endif
    /*
     * When (nr_dirtied >= nr_dirtied_pause), it's time to call
     * balance_dirty_pages() for a dirty throttling pause:
     */
    int             nr_dirtied;
    int             nr_dirtied_pause;
    /* Start of a write-and-pause period: */
    unsigned long           dirty_paused_when;

#ifdef CONFIG_LATENCYTOP
    int             latency_record_count;
    struct latency_record       latency_record[LT_SAVECOUNT];
#endif
    /*
     * Time slack values; these are used to round up poll() and
     * select() etc timeout values. These are in nanoseconds.
     */
    u64             timer_slack_ns;
    u64             default_timer_slack_ns;

#if defined(CONFIG_KASAN_GENERIC) || defined(CONFIG_KASAN_SW_TAGS)
    unsigned int            kasan_depth;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_KCSAN
    struct kcsan_ctx        kcsan_ctx;
#ifdef CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS
    struct irqtrace_events      kcsan_save_irqtrace;
#endif
#endif

#if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_KUNIT)
    struct kunit            *kunit_test;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER
    /* Index of current stored address in ret_stack: */
    int             curr_ret_stack;
    int             curr_ret_depth;

    /* Stack of return addresses for return function tracing: */
    struct ftrace_ret_stack     *ret_stack;

    /* Timestamp for last schedule: */
    unsigned long long      ftrace_timestamp;

    /*
     * Number of functions that haven't been traced
     * because of depth overrun:
     */
    atomic_t            trace_overrun;

    /* Pause tracing: */
    atomic_t            tracing_graph_pause;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_TRACING
    /* State flags for use by tracers: */
    unsigned long           trace;

    /* Bitmask and counter of trace recursion: */
    unsigned long           trace_recursion;
#endif /* CONFIG_TRACING */

#ifdef CONFIG_KCOV
    /* See kernel/kcov.c for more details. */

    /* Coverage collection mode enabled for this task (0 if disabled): */
    unsigned int            kcov_mode;

    /* Size of the kcov_area: */
    unsigned int            kcov_size;

    /* Buffer for coverage collection: */
    void                *kcov_area;

    /* KCOV descriptor wired with this task or NULL: */
    struct kcov         *kcov;

    /* KCOV common handle for remote coverage collection: */
    u64             kcov_handle;

    /* KCOV sequence number: */
    int             kcov_sequence;

    /* Collect coverage from softirq context: */
    unsigned int            kcov_softirq;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_MEMCG
    struct mem_cgroup       *memcg_in_oom;
    gfp_t               memcg_oom_gfp_mask;
    int             memcg_oom_order;

    /* Number of pages to reclaim on returning to userland: */
    unsigned int            memcg_nr_pages_over_high;

    /* Used by memcontrol for targeted memcg charge: */
    struct mem_cgroup       *active_memcg;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP
    struct request_queue        *throttle_queue;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_UPROBES
    struct uprobe_task      *utask;
#endif
#if defined(CONFIG_BCACHE) || defined(CONFIG_BCACHE_MODULE)
    unsigned int            sequential_io;
    unsigned int            sequential_io_avg;
#endif
    struct kmap_ctrl        kmap_ctrl;
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP
    unsigned long           task_state_change;
#endif
    int             pagefault_disabled;
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
    struct task_struct      *oom_reaper_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    struct vm_struct        *stack_vm_area;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /* A live task holds one reference: */
    refcount_t          stack_refcount;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_LIVEPATCH
    int patch_state;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_SECURITY
    /* Used by LSM modules for access restriction: */
    void                *security;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_GCC_PLUGIN_STACKLEAK
    unsigned long           lowest_stack;
    unsigned long           prev_lowest_stack;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_X86_MCE
    void __user         *mce_vaddr;
    __u64               mce_kflags;
    u64             mce_addr;
    __u64               mce_ripv : 1,
                    mce_whole_page : 1,
                    __mce_reserved : 62;
    struct callback_head        mce_kill_me;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_KRETPROBES
    struct llist_head               kretprobe_instances;
#endif

    /*
     * New fields for task_struct should be added above here, so that
     * they are included in the randomized portion of task_struct.
     */
    randomized_struct_fields_end

    /* CPU-specific state of this task: */
    struct thread_struct        thread;

    /*
     * WARNING: on x86, 'thread_struct' contains a variable-sized
     * structure.  It *MUST* be at the end of 'task_struct'.
     *
     * Do not put anything below here!
     */
};
```

As you can see it is a very long structure. The ELF file specifies mostly the virtual addresses of the different segments. Today, some executables are even relocatable so they keep information on how to relocate them before runtime. The Android OS which runs on top of Linux is using only relocatable executables for security matters (ASLR).

The ELF file has a header. The header tells where to find the program header. The program header contains segments. Each segment can be loadable or other. If it is loadable. then the OS should just take the segment and load it at the virtual address specified by the segment header. So the ELF file has a header which point to a program header which points to segments header which point to the actual code (or segment of code). In the case of dynamically linked stuff, it is more complex. I'm not totally sure how that works so I'll leave this to you to understand.

One important fields of the task_struct is the mm field which is pointer to an mm_struct. It contains the memory map for the process. Also, there are a lot of #ifdef accompanied with #endif depending on the configuration of compilation and depending on the system you compile for.

I leave it as an exercice to find the task_struct in the source code. You can search the source code on https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source.